# If the leading coefficient of a polynomial is negative, does the greatest common factor also have to be negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

For example, is the GCF of $(-3)x^2 + 6x + 12$ positive $3$ or negative $3$? In general, when should the GCF be negative and when should it be positive?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the greatest common factor of two or more integers is the largest positive integer that is a factor of each of those integers.  Hence,
$\operatorname{GCF}(-3x^2 + 6x + 12) = 3$.

Comment: I see. So is the GCF always positive, even when it’s between two negative integers?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: That said, you will sometimes find it useful to factor out a negative number.  For instance, if you are asked to factor the polynomial $-2x^2 + 8x + 24$, factoring out $-2$ may make it easier for you to factor the polynomial completely.  $-2x^2 + 8x + 24 = -2(x^2 - 4x - 12) = -2(x - 6)(x + 2)$.